# How do I delete a question on the SE app?

Tags: discussion

I know this is a meta question, but I don't have enough rep to do so

How do I delete a question on the SE app?

Answer (score 5):

You don't unfortunately.

It's functionality that [doesn't exist on the SE app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216962/allow-us-to-vote-to-delete-from-the-android-app) because the API that it uses doesn't allow you to view a post that is deleted.

There would need to be either a change to said API or a place to send you after deletion.